# I checked the xenomai task in kernelshark and the results are strange

Tags: linux, kernel, xenomai

[image]

Using the stress-ng tool on Linux
"# stress-ng -c0 -l100" gives 100% load to cpu, and xenomai has a run time of 750us for 1ms cycle.

watch -n0 "cat / proc / xenomai / stat"
By command, we were able to verify the use of 75% CPU.
However, I checked the cpu quota of xenomai and linux using tracd-cmd
I expected xenomai to use more cpu because its priority was higher than normal Linux, but the result was not so. The task that is "ecat-embedded" in the picture is the xenomai task.
Why are these results coming out?